# Does a Question About a Programming Lawsuit Belong on Stack Overflow or its Legal Counterpart?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Consider the questions,

"Can a CSS stylesheet be copyrighted?" or "Is there any precedent for a lawsuit based on a PHP code base?"

Are these questions about programming or law? Which Stack Exchange site do they belong on?

Comment: It's a legal question, and the correct SE site would be "none of them".

Comment: The usual caveat you see on answers to that sort of question is "IANAL" ("I am not a lawyer"). My favorite sign-off when I saw someone giving high-level legal ... guidance ... to someone they didn't know online was: *"Caveat: I **am** a lawyer, but I'm not **your** lawyer, and the above is not legal advice. For legal advice, engage the services of a lawyer."*

Comment: [Related question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25363/is-there-a-stack-exchange-site-for-law-questions-if-not-why-not)

Comment: We can't program law (which is not to say lawmakers do not resemble artificial unintelligence). Since SO is about programming an law is not programmed, it should be clearly off topic. Beyond that... anyone taking legal advice from random strangers on the internet, no matter how large the number is next to their name, is clearly looking in the wrong place.

Comment: I have three thoughts on this. First of all, you should spend some time reading up on basic copyright laws. They're not that complex.

Second, if you did, you'd see that anything that is rendered in any tangible medium is covered by copyright laws from the moment it is rendered. But you need to file a copyright registration in order to bring a lawsuit for infringement.

Third, I heartily recommend a LegalShield membership for these kinds of questions. An IP lawyer will cost you about 1/2 year's membership fees per hour, and will give you the same information for basic questions like these.

Comment: Note that the second example question has factual answers which would not even resemble legal advice. You might need someone experienced in doing case research to answer it well (especially in the negative), of course.

Comment: about *Which Stack Exchange* that would be again country dependent in germany you **have** the copyright for live for ever written

Comment: @T.J. - if he was a lawyer, he was probably lying...

Comment: If you really want a legal SE site, [There's an Area51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/67858/law) that's looking like it might make it to a beta

Answer (score 67):

I do not agree with the "hire a lawyer sentiment". Asking about the general law without specific legal advice isn't inherently bad and doesn't replace a lawyer anyway.

It's off topic on Stack Overflow since it's not a specific *programming* question. There are a few relevant proposals for websites in the Stack Exchange network in Area 51. None are launched yet.

- <strike>[Intellectual Property](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66416/intellectual-property) - questions about patents, copyrights, trademarks, trade secrets, and any other areas of intellectual property law.</strike> deleted.
- [Law](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/67858/law) (**Update** Law has been launched!)- for experts in the law, and those who want to find our more about specific local, national or international laws, or those who want to find out about concepts regarding laws in general. The site is not for specific legal advice.

Note that http://opensource.stackexchange.com might also be relevant here.

Comment: Thank you for the constructive answer

Comment: The line between "information on the law" and "legal advice" is a really fine one, and many consumers won't be able to tell the difference... so, while I agree, it should be OK to seek knowledge without hiring a lawyer, when you do it in the wrong venue (such as at SO), the quickest answer is always going to be "hire a lawyer".

Comment: The other answer doesn't say, "for information about the law hire a lawyer".  It says, for "**useful** legal advice".  Which is completely correct.

Comment: Jason If there was a website - like any of the many legal forums there would be a huge disclaimer anyway. @BenVoigt you can get a lot of useful legal advice without hiring a lawyer. This is not a replacement. Anyway, the answer isn't about "should we open a law.se or copyright.se" site anyway - it's about whether or not there are places where this can be asked on StackExchange - my answer is - there are two proposals and none are in beta yet.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: In most areas for non-lawyers to provide legal advice is illegal ("practicing law without a license/bar privilege/whatever").  That doesn't mean you can't get plenty of useful commentary from non-lawyers (like what I just gave you), but it is not "legal advice".

Comment: Yes, be careful with you say "legal advice", that phrase means something specific and it entails legal obligations.

Comment: I have enough problems with the compiler and linker.  I don't want to add 'prosecutors and judges' to the list.

Comment: Although the OP's question is not specific to programming, it *is* relevant to programming.  Most of us have to deal with tech-specific legal issues (NDAs, patents, software licensing, copyrights, etc.) and there should be a SE site specific to those issues.  Such a site could have a big disclaimer banner that reminds everyone visiting that the content is not official legal advice.

Comment: *"Asking about the general law without specific legal advice isn't inherently bad"* - +1. I get tired of reading about how reverse engineering is illegal under DMCA by folks who don't know the basics of the law. Its perfectly legal is under DMCA (Section 1205 provides proper exemptions for Reverse Engineering and Security Testing).

Comment: I agree with this answer completely. I think the question might even be on-topic for programmers.se in addition to the two mentioned.

Answer (score 38):

They are not on-topic for SO. If you want useful legal advice, hire a lawyer.

Comment: But, taking legal advice from random people on the internet is fun!

Comment: Most lawyers will tell you to [do this](http://img4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120827072951/breakingbad/images/a/a6/5x7_bank.png). I prefer things that don't involve expenses.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - *real* lawyers pretty much *have to* disclaim themselves, because they entail certain obligations for things that amount to "legal advice".  In another forum there was a law student that had a similar disclaimer to the one you post, I'm sure it's been drilled into law students since asking for advice best gotten from professionals (MDs, JDs, CPAs, and other acronyms you must go to a lot of school to put after your name) from random people on the internet became a bona fide thing.

Comment: That said, I believe the *real* question most people are asking is, "am I so far out in left field here that I shouldn't even pursue this?"  The answer, always, is that a talented (I'll shy away from the word "good") lawyer can usually make *something* out of your situation... and a *good* lawyer will tell you if you should try.  Anyone not a lawyer can only provide you the same information you can find by searching the web yourself.

Comment: @Jason a lot of information in StackOverflow is stuff independent research on the web can help you find for yourself.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum as long as it's on topic, then you can make a case for that being OK (though some people don't like it even then).

Comment: @AndrewMedico : Or please support this [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/67858/law/68811#68811)