# Is [sarbanesoxley] violating Stack Overflow laws?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, review-queues, burninate-request, scope

[There is a question asking about legal requirements for data-retention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35522868/data-retention-periods-sensible-choices-or-the-emperors-new-clothes).

Crossing off the advice on whether it should be here...

- *a specific programming problem?* - **Nope**
- *a software algorithm?* - **Nope**
- *software tools commonly used by programmers?* - **not directly**
- *a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development?* - **more like data-management, not software development**

It is tagged [sarbanesoxley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sarbanesoxley). Not only does the post appear off-topic, so too the tag. I guess the closest it gets to being in scope is that the law act effects *software tools commonly used by programmers*.

Break down of other questions in this tag:

[Does SOX restrict access to QA environments or just production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548738/does-sox-restrict-access-to-qa-environments-or-just-production) 
This seems like its more (not entirely) related to server management than it does software development.

[Scrum Compliance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651320/scrum-compliance) its not directly talking about a developer tool; more how a law relates to a time-management methodology.

It seems these posts are more applicable in other areas? Either server-vault or Law Beta?

*Although [Does a Question About a Programming Lawsuit Belong on Stack Overflow or its Legal Counterpart?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272705) answers whether the original top-most post belongs here, it doesn't directly answer whether the [sarbanesoxley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sarbanesoxley) tag should be removed.*

*The tags have already been removed.*

Comment: Yes, this question is off topic for a multitude of closable reasons.

Comment: And the tag? there doesn't appear to be any posts yet that directly have a programming-problem related to the law.

Comment: There are only 2 other questions, both of them ~7 years old, far too old to migrate anywhere. Vote to close them as off-topic (why haven't you done this yet?) and/or retag.

Comment: I've removed the tag from the 3 questions that were tagged with it. Hopefully it won't come up again.

Comment: @CodyGray I made the mistake of voting too broad. I wasn't sure if only off-topic where migrated, so I retracted.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ does that mean the tag should also be deleted? if so, if I edit this post will that make it not a duplicate?

Comment: @MeirionHughes The posts should be closed as off-topic, the tag should be burinated.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Aren't pun titles punished on here?

Comment: @MeirionHughes It was at least a good tradition for tag burination suggests.

Comment: The day puns start being punished is the day Meta is no longer Meta.