# Is question about licence or legal advice concerning programming off topic?

Tags: discussion

I answered today a question about law advices on a repository name and legal trademark for a repository on GitHub.

That question wasn't very well accepted by SO community, at least by the first users who have seen the question before to put it on hold as off topic.
And my answer could surely be improved ("[Not a lawyer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272705/does-a-question-about-a-programming-lawsuit-belong-on-stack-overflow-or-its-lega)", etc.)

I'm not agree with them as this question is about (open source) programming, and I think it's an interesting/usefull question.
Should I hire a lawyer ?

Is it off topic to talk about open source licence software and legal stuff about programs ?

Should I do not answer at all in the first place ?
Should I edit the question to appear in reopen review queue to make it a chance to exist ?

Or just let it go ?

Comment: That question deals with licensing, but the same applies to any law/lawyer/etc questions

Comment: @TinyGiant Thanks for the link. I will flag this as belong to another SE site from now on.

Comment: Blatantly off-topic would be a better choice in my opinion, let other sites worry about their own topicality. No one likes having someone take a crap on their lawn and having that person tell them that we told them it was OK.

Comment: Ok, you're right, I'll do that. Maybe with a comment like buy yourself a law book and figure it out on your own.